# Javascript or Jquery Image Pop-Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I have looked at many of these galleries and displays, but none of them I have tested seem to do exactly what I want.

My requirements are as follows.

Click a thumbnail and the image is displayed as a lightbox.
*No problem achieving this*

Arrows inside left and right borders for navigating Next and Previous AND also achieving this by clicking anywhere on the left half of the image for Previous and anywhere on the right for Next.

Close button : Option to place in any corner of image DIV.

Description above or below, which will allow HTML tags.

Show current image as (4 of 20) etc in the description area.

And finally when displayed on a smartphone's browser allow finger swiping, to navigate from image to image.

I do not need fancy fades, just simple replacing one image with the next navigated to.

Can anyone recommend a javascript/jquery script that fulfils all the above and is easy to implement with minimal change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colorbox is really good and easily customisable. http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

I believe it does all of what you want minus the finger swiping but should be another jQuery library you could hook in for that.

Comment: Thank you.  Colorbox certainly looks a possibility and this link seems as though it may answer my swipe request [http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library]

Answer (score 1):

Try fancybox:

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

I've used this many times and it should support all the features you're looking for.

Otherwise, try http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

Colorbox is easy, powerful and tested in the common browsers:

Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8, 9, Opera 11.

(I personally use this one all the time)

Colorbox does NOT have a close button on the top corner though.